# GET result empty when using transformer with api platform and symfony

Tags: symfony, symfony4, api-platform.com

I'm using api platform in symfony (4) and without using a transformer (or rather: without using the output property) I'm getting the correct result.
However as I need to transform a logo (add a path) I need to integrate a transformer. As a result the response is empty.

ApiResource definition in Entity:

```
/**
 *
 * @ApiResource(
 *     collectionOperations = {
 *      "get"
 *     },
 *     normalizationContext={"groups" = {"frontend:read"}},
 *     itemOperations={
        "get"
 *     },
 *     order={"name"="ASC"},
 *     paginationEnabled=false,
 *     output=EntityApiOutput::class
 * )
 */
```

EntityApiOutput:

```
class EntityApiOutput
{
    public $id;
}
```

EntityApiOutputDataTransformer:

```
class EntityApiOutputDataTransformer implements DataTransformerInterface
{   
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function transform($object, string $to, array $context = [])
    {
        $eao = new EntityApiOutput();
        $eao->id = 3;

        return $eao;
    }

    public function supportsTransformation($data, string $to, array $context = []): bool
    {
        return EntityApiOutput::class === $to && $data instanceof Entity;
    }
}
```

entry in services.yaml:

```
App\DataTransformer\EntityApiOutputDataTransformer:
   tags:
     - { name: api_platform.data_transformer }
```

I simplified the transformer for reading purposes.

Putting a

```
dump($eao)
exit;
```

into the transform method confirms that the transformer is called and the EntityApiOutput object is filled.

Comment: If you use -> normalizationContext={"groups" = {"frontend:read"}} you have to write that groups about that properties you want to get in the result

Answer (score 2):

Mhm unfortunately the api platform doc forgets to mention to also put the group into the output class:

```
class EntityApiOutput
{
    /*
     *
     * @Groups({"frontend:read"})
     */
    public $id;
}
```

That's how it should look like.